# How to stop specific code from running? In pygame

Tags: python

How would I stop the code from if something happens, for example:

```
while True:
    if numbers_equals_four and people_equals_four:
        #stop the code below from running
    
    
    numbers += 1
    people += 1
    
    if numbers == 4:
        numbers_equals_four = True
    if people == 4:
        people_equal_four = True
```

Thanks!

Comment: you understand that if `numbers == 4`, then `numbers == 2` cannot also be `True`, right?

Comment: Yeah I don't know why I did that I am really dumb

Comment: I changed the code to make sense

Comment: look at `break` and `continuous` statements. `break` will break out of the loop, while `continue` will move to next iteration of the loop. Now, once the both conditions are True and if you use `continue` it will most likely turn into infinite loop - the code provided does not allow that once the condition is True it become False again.

Answer (score 0):

As other's have already told you, the statement `numbers == 2` will never hold if `numbers == 4` has returned `True` prior to that without any changes to numbers.
I assume you tried to make a quick example.

I'd recommend to always try to use a statement for your `while` loop, instead of just writing `while True`, in the case of your code `while numbers !=2:` might be a better solution after some restructuring.

If you can't find a way to do the above, you could use `break`.
Break 'breaks' out of the current for or while loop you are iterating through.

So your code would look like this:

```py
while True:

    numbers += 1
    if numbers == 4:
        if numbers == 2:         
            break
        numbers -= 1
```

But again, please note that `numbers == 2` will never hold, therefor `break` will never be executed and your code will not be able to escape your loop.

W3Schools has a very nice [beginner course on python](https://www.w3schools.com/python/default.asp), and also has a [section on the break keyword](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_keyword_break.asp) with the ability to run code snippets, be sure to check it out.